# How can I get a list of all pre-installed server modules in PHP?

Tags: php, apache

Is there a way to check all pre-installed modules on my Apache server ?

I want the solution in PHP.

Comment: Not a DV, but I imagine people thought this could be [found with a search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=get+apache+modules+in+php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List of loaded Apache modules:

```
print_r(apache_get_modules());
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-get-modules.php

Comment: Actually,I wanted to know if my webhost has enabled .htaccess (Rewrite module)..Anyway Thank you For the answer, it is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

See the [get_loaded_extensions()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-loaded-extensions.php) function. It should be what you asre looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To get all loaded PHP modules:

1. You can run `php -m` from the command line
2. You can use [get_loaded_extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-loaded-extensions.php) PHP function
3. You can use [phpinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) function to output a lot of information about your PHP environment (including loaded modules).